# Failed an audit on a post listed as spam or offensive, to me it looked like just a wrong answer

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, spam, specific-audit

This [review had an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32891470) about reflection with a link to a repo from the author of the answer.

Screenshot for <10k users:

> [image]

However bad the answer is, I clicked Looks Ok. I did so having viewed the repo, read the comments that it didn't work, and reviewed the "edit:" line.

It didn't appear to be link only, as there was additional information in the answer on using the repo.

My best theory on reflection is that I should have considered it spam because there was no disclosure the author of the post was the author of the repo. I assumed because the username of both was the same that was sufficient disclosure.

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: The link overlaps with the username. That's an excellent audit

Comment: "*I assumed because the username of both was the same that was sufficient disclosure.*" - Actually, no, that's not sufficient. The disclosure has to be explicitly stated in the answer itself.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine OP knows that the link overlaps with the username. They say so in the question.

Comment: @cigien Yes, but that's still the reason it's a good audit. All the information to determine it's spam (or at least that it isn't 100% fine) is completely contained within the audit

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Yes, the information about the affiliation is in the post. The OP doesn't appear to be suggesting that the affiliation is subtle, just that they weren't aware that the disclosure has to be explicit. Which is reasonable, as I'm not sure that requirement is mentioned in the help center. It's not in the [promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) page at least: it's not unreasonable to assume that the name and website matching exactly would count as sufficient disclosure.

Comment: @cigien https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion: "However, if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer, you must **disclose your affiliation in your post**."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've correctly spotted the issue with the answer, i.e. the author failed to *explicitly* disclose their affiliation in the text of the answer. The help page on [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) doesn't make this part as clear as it could. It's not unreasonable to assume that the username and linked website matching exactly counts as disclosure, and in fact, users make this mistake fairly frequently, and correct it once it's pointed out to them.

Disclosure needs to be explicit - this doesn't have to be anything formal, just a "I wrote the article here <link>" is sufficient. Without this disclosure, the post is technically spam, and should be treated as such from a review queue. The particular answer you've linked clearly lacks explicit disclosure and so it's actually a fairly clear review audit.

In the wild, it often makes sense to leave a comment pointing out the missing disclosure rather than raising a spam flag directly (though such a flag is likely to be marked helpful). There's a standard comment that's frequently used in these situations (which also mentions the need to be explicit about the affiliation):

> When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation *in the answer*](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: "*The particular answer you've linked clearly lacks explicit disclosure [...]*": Yep, completely agree, the Answerer keeps using "*this Library*" to refer to it (in the Answer + at least 1 Comment, from the Screenshot), like if they "just happened to discover it", and no Disclosure at all that they are in any way "involved"... => Boomerang Effect as "pretty suspicious" once one finds out...

Comment: What would it take to get the help page updated?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It depends. Some help pages can be edited by site moderators, and others can only be edited by staff. I'm not sure which category the promotion help page falls in, though I suspect this would be the latter as this is a page containing guidance that applies across the network.

Comment: In either case, it would require buy in from the mod team or staff to make the change. It's happened in a few cases before, but they're not common and usually requires there to be a clear case of the existing guidance being misleading or lacking in crucial information.

Comment: I think "you *must* disclose your affiliation in your post" at the very top is about as clear as it can get. So, it's not clear to me what needs to be updated, @Karl. Yeah, getting a change requires staff involvement, but I know who to ping, and we've gotten that specific page updated a couple of times in the past. Please create a separate feature request on Meta asking for the changes that you want. That'll allow us to iterate on the verbiage as necessary, and then I can ping a CM with a fully-formed request, including actual textual changes. (Not to mention it won't get lost in comments.)

Comment: The unclear part is *what is deemed disclosure*.

Comment: Sometimes, authors don't understand that they need to explicitly state in their post that they are the author of the linked article, even after repeated requests. We had an example of that a few days ago, now deleted: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420696/my-post-was-deleted-for-plagiarising-my-own-paper

Comment: Effectively, *anything*, @Karl. Something as simple as using the correct pronoun ("I"/"my") is sufficient to count as disclosure. There just needs to be *some mention of it* in the post itself.

Comment: Err, that wasn't the issue or the misunderstanding there, @PM2Ring.

Comment: I think that it is perfectly reasonable that a person who reads the help page, as it currently exists, would conclude that "my username is in the URL" constitutes "some mention of it".

Comment: The user name is not *in the answer*, so that clearly cannot count as disclosure "in the answer" or "in your post". There has to be actual mention of the affiliation in the body/text of the post. That seems abundantly clear to me.

Comment: It was one of the issues, Cody. The OP complained repeatedly that they'd got the 100 point penalty for spamming.

Comment: Mere lack of disclosure of affiliation was not why the penalty was issued, @PM2Ring. Disclosure was *not* one of the issues, it was only one of many sea-lioning strategies.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to derail the current discussion. I just wanted to point out that it's not necessarily obvious to everyone that explicit attribution in the body of the post is required, and it can be hard to communicate that properly to some people.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I fell for that from the help. It seemed to be "in" the answer by virtue of being the same username (author section of the answer) and several comments from the author showing the username. **I'm properly schooled now**. Maybe adding "in the answer **body**" would have helped me to avoid conflating "in the answer" with "in the answer, author, or URL".